# Python Native Implementation of Mixed Integer Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, python, mixed-integer-programming, simplex-method

Is it possible to have pure Python implementation of Mixed Integer Linear Programming,
something similar to mip, pulp, cvxpy, etc. -

but such simple as https://github.com/ispaneli/lippy - it is Simplex-method based implementations of such methods as Branch and bound, Cutting-plane and another methods.
Those methods are full-integer solvers, which does not work for bigger number of variables - some methods go to infinite loops, another - returns zeroes-only solve.

There is a requirement to solve a problem, which returns BOTH fractional and integer variables.

Probably it is something simplex-like problem, where some of solved variables should be integers.

The thing is at this case it's impossible to import c-based libs like mip.

So question is:
Are there similar solutions as github.com/ispaneli/lippy ,
but for problems where some of solved variables should be integers?

Those lippy lib methods do not work, return zeroes or stacks infinite loops